# Can we deduce this inequality?

Tags: inequality

If given $a>b>c>0$, can we deduce $b-c<a$? You can also use the fact that $b+c>a$. It seems intuitvely true as the difference between two numbers less than $a$ is surely less than $a$? But I am stuck on how to prove.
Thanks.

Comment: $b-c$ is less than $b$, which is less than $a$

Comment: I would like to ask, if I start with $a>b$, can I subtract $c$ from just one side of the equation? Everywhere online says you must only subtract same from both sides

Comment: What you subtract from one side, subtract from the other to maintain a true inequality. But also realize that observing $b - c < b < a$ is not the same as subtracting from either side of a set of inequalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the inequality $c>0$. We can take the negative of both sides, which will give us $-c<0$(remember we need to flip the sign of the inequality), and add $b$ to both sides giving us $b-c<b$, or $b>b-c$(this should be intuitively obvious as $c>0$).

Now, we know that $a>b$(this is given) and we know that $b>b-c$(from above). So, we can deduce that $a>b>b-c$, and hence $a>b-c$ or equivalently $\boxed{b-c<a}$.

Let me know if you have any additional questions!

Comment: Yeah just one question, if I start with $a>b$ can I just subtract $c$ from the right hand side as I know that $a$ will still be bigger than the right hand side if I subtract a positive number $c$?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I'm doing here. I'm just adding a bunch of extra steps so it's 100% clear; you could just go straight to $b>b-c$ and $a>b>b-c$.

Comment: But everywhere online it says you must only add/subtract the same quantity from both sides?

Comment: Yeah, this is true. This is why it would be generally considered(imo) "wrong" or at best unclear to say that $a>b$ implies $a>b-c$. However, if we add the extra step $b>b-c$(comes from $c>0$) then we have $a>b>b-c$ which is much more clear.

Comment: If I said something like $x>2$ then its also correct to write $x>1$ , but I cannot forget that $x>2$ aswell so we should really write $x>2>1$, is this sort of what you are saying?

Comment: That's the gist of it; when you're dealing with numbers of course it's very clear that $x>2$ implies $x>1$ but generally just write out the extra steps when dealing with variables; the clearer you can be the better.

Comment: So what I am asking is that, to get from $x>2$ to $x>1$ we have taken $1$ from the right hand side, I guess this is justified?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just generally prefer to write out the extra steps to be more clear.

Comment: I found a good way of putting across what I meant, if you do the same thing to both sides then both statements are equivalent, but two statements can imply another without equivalency, sort of like the $x>1$ and $x>2$ case, one is a "tighter" restriction and its not an if and only if case.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, simply start with $a>b$ then $a-b>0>-c$

Answer (score 0):

Since $a >b > c>0$, you have the following: $a>b$ and $c >0$.

In particular by adding $-c$ on the inequality $a>b$ on both sides you get:

$$a-c>b-c$$

However, since $c>0$, then $a>a-c$, and so:
$$a>a-c> b-c$$
The restraint that $b>c$ is not needed (notice even, if you have $b\leq c$, then your inequality asks if $a$ is greater than $b-c$ which is not positive, since $a$ is positive then surely $a>b-c$).